# htaccess RegEx that shortens URL with exceptions

Tags: regex

Right now, I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

to match any username at the end of the site like www.mywebsite.com/username

How do I make regex make exceptions for certain directories like

'popular/songs/' or
'addsong/list/'

so that www.mywebsite.com/popular/songs/ does not direct to the profile of someone whose name is 'popular'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add before this command option you need escape. This condition escape start with any of these conditions

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(popular|index\.php|content|scripts|upload|admin|robots\.txt)
```

Comment: @TheJagganator Works this for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it sends me to a 404 page :(

Comment: Yes. This command escape the default index.php ... With this command you need /popular/song directory with index.php page to resolve your request